# How to connect to MySQL from QGIS in Ubuntu10?

Tags: qgis, mysql

I have just installed Quantum GIS 1.8.0 on my Ubuntu 10. I want to add a MySql table as a data source but I can't see any options for connecting to mysql.

Can any one guide me how to connect to mysql?

N.B : Options for Available Database Types in Qgis are MSSQL,ODBC,PostgreSQL and ESRI Personal GEO Database.

Comment: no,It's not duplicate,that post for whome ,user can see mysql option in adding vactor layer[link](http://getspatial.com/gisblog/qgis-vector-data-connection),In my case I can't see option for mysql :(

Comment: I'm sorry for being wrong. i have deleted dublicated message.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the package libmysql.
I configured a vm with ubuntu 10.04 and after installing libmysql (it came with mysql-client) it works properly.

Try it and post here your results.

Comment: I had already loaded mysql-client,I Know that without mysql-client we can't make connection from qgis,now I has loaded eVis Plugin which use for mysql connection but following error occur    "New Database connection requested...
Connection to [localhost.test_db] failed: Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

Comment: Did you already reinstall mysql-client and qgis? Try to completely remove mysql-client and qgis (purge and delete paths) before reinstalling. And about others dbs? Did you try to connect with them?

Comment: yes , I had completely removed qgis and msql-client then I had install again ,I have no any other database,I work with only MySql db.